# Value of type 'x' has no member 'lowercased

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9.4

I'm try to implement search bar to my table view. But I am getting this error 
     Value of type 'getUserData' has no member 'lowercased' on this code

```
filteredDataBySearch = dataSourceArray.filter({ (data:String) -> Bool in
    return data.lowercased().rangeOfString(searchText.lowercased()) != nil
})
```

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var FSuserLIst: UITableView!
var dataSourceArray1 = [getUserData]()
var dataSourceArray2 = [getUserData]()
var dataSourceArray3 = [getUserData]()
var dataSourceArray4 = [getUserData]()
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
var showSearchResults = false
var filteredDataBySearch = [getUserData]()
```

And here's my function for searching

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    showSearchResults = true
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()

}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if segmentedData.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        filteredDataBySearch = dataSourceArray.filter({ (data:String) -> Bool in

            return data.lowercased().rangeOfString(searchText.lowercased()) != nil
        })

        if searchText != "" {

            showSearchResults = true
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        } else {
            showSearchResults = false
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        }
    }

    else if segmentedData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        filteredDataBySearch = dataSourceArray1.filter({ (data:String) -> Bool in

            return data.lowercased().rangeOfString(searchText.lowercased()) != nil
        })

        if searchText != "" {

            showSearchResults = true
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        } else {
            showSearchResults = false
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        }
    }

    else if segmentedData.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

        filteredDataBySearch = dataSourceArray2.filter({ (data:String) -> Bool in

            return data.lowercased().rangeOfString(searchText.lowercased()) != nil
        })

        if searchText != "" {

            showSearchResults = true
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        } else {
            showSearchResults = false
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        }
    }

  else if segmentedData.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {

        filteredDataBySearch = dataSourceArray3.filter({ (data:String) -> Bool in

            return data.lowercased().rangeOfString(searchText.lowercased()) != nil
        })

        if searchText != "" {

            showSearchResults = true
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        } else {
            showSearchResults = false
            self.FSuserLIst.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

"getUserData" is the class that's having more than 10 var and it's located in the another swift file.

I'm really appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: `getUserData` is not String, why you are trying to filter it into String? Also a class name should never be named like that, should be `UserData` or something

Comment: What should i filter? I'm new in this things... Thank you.

Comment: Add getUserData class. Class name always begin with Capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert the getUserData class to lowercase there. You want to access a string within this class then convert that. I haven't tested this but you are looking for something along these lines.

```
filteredDataBySearch = dataSourceArray.filter({ (userData:MyUserDataClass) -> Bool in

    let data = userData.myStringInThisClass.lowercased()

    return data.contains(searchText.lowercased())
})
```

This would be getting a variable within the class that is a string and converting it to lowercase.

As a side note, the typical convention is to use caps for a class name, ie. `MyClass`